# What is the difference between あまり and そんなに? Are they always interchangable?

Tags: grammar

How do I use あまり and そんなに in negative sentences? It would be a great help if it was explained with various examples of あまり vs そんなに.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Japanese.SE! Please also add your own example sentences, where you think あまり and そんなに are interchangeable. (You also have some typos in your question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update: as Chocolate-san pointed in the comment, this answer is wrong.  I didn't realize which part そんなに would apply to (probably thought of そんな).  Not sure if I have to remove it, please feel free to do so.**

---

Since you mention negative sentences specifically, it seems that you are trying to translate into Japanese something like "It's not *that much* interesting", and puzzling why そんなに doesn't fit.

In a negative sentence そんなに means *that much not X* in a sense *not X beyond expectation*, while あんまり simply means *not much X*, thus they are not interchangeable.  Consider the following dialogue:

A:「**そんなに**[面白]{おもしろ}くない[映画]{えいが}を[観]{み}たいの？」- Do you want to see the movie that is **that much** uninteresting?

B:「**あんまり**[面白]{おもしろ}くないけど、[主人公]{しゅじんこう}はかっこいい」- Though it's not **that much** interesting, the main character is cool.

Note that A evaluates the movie as a total waste and beyond (how a movie can ever be that much uninteresting?), while B suggests that the movie may still be somewhat interesting (though not that much interesting).

Comment: `そんなに面白くない映画を見たいのか` -- ちょっと変です、、、というか普通の日本語話者ならそれ読むと「そんなに～したいのか」(Do) you want to do ~~ so bad って読んでしまうと思うんですけど・・

Comment: *That much uninteresting* is a little hard to understand because the polarity-sensitive item *much* isn't licensed by the following lexical negation *uninteresting* in the same way that it would be by a preceding *not*.

Comment: @Chocolate I kinda hoped か would mean sarcasm like in 知るか (A thinks the whole idea of wanting to see that movie is crazy).  Removed.

Comment: @snailplane The translation is meant to be more literal rather than literate to show different meanings of "that much".

Comment: @Chocolate Ah, I probably got you point wrong, you mean the sentence is parsed as そんなに(面白くない映画を)見たいの? - Right? - Then my answer is off...

Comment: Hey All Thanks for the explanations.It gave me clear understanding.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I don't think they mean exactly the same, there's a difference not only in usage, but in the nuance it brings...

> あまり or あんまり - Much
>
> そんなに - That much, to that extent.

While あまり is used to simply state that you cannot perform something very well

I think that そんなに is kind of a "comparison", there is an established standard to that action that you're supposed to perform, and you're stating that you can or cannot perform it to that established point/extent.

Examples:

**あんまり:**

> その新しいゲームやったことある？ - Sono Atarashii Geemu Yatta koto aru? (**have you already played that new game?**).
>
> ごめん、ゲームのことは**あんまり**わからない。 - Gomen, Geemu no koto wa anmari wakaranai. (**Sorry, I don't understand much about games.**)

**そんなに:**

> ドイツ語で本が書けますか？ - Doitsugo de Hon ga kakemasu ka? (**Can you write a book in German?**)
>
> もちろん、僕は書けないよ。僕はまだ**そんなに**上手じゃないよ。 - Mochiron, Boku wa kakenai yo. Boku wa mada, sonna ni jouzu janai yo. (**Of course I cannot write it. I'm still not that fluent.**)

Comment: +1, but I think 「ゲームのこと"は"あんまりわからない」 sounds more natural.

Comment: @Yosh I will edit it!! 教えてくれてありがとう^ ^

Comment: @FelipeOliveira For the same reason, the previous sentence would be more natural without が: "その新しいゲーム(を)やったこと(は)ある？". These を and は are optional, but it'd be a little more better without them.

Comment: @user4092 I edited it! I'm just a little afraid that making an answer perfectly natural might be confusing for beginners, all the particles drops and things like that, but I guess in this case it's ok. Thank you!

Comment: I think I should explain the reason. The point of using zero particle or は is to indicate things as a topic (when the sense of contrast is redundant, zero particle is better). You want express both その新しいゲーム and やったこと as a topic here for the listener to follow.

Comment: @user4092 I thought you dropped the particle, just cause it's more commom to do so in common speech. Don't you think there's a contrast in "Did you play that new game?", isn't contrasting to the other games, that are not new? Thank you

Comment: @FelipeOliveira It depends. If you mean it, it should be as it is. In spoken Japanese, topical expressions are more diverse and zero particle is a distinct grammatical category beyond mere omission. By the way, zero particle one is close to その新しいゲーム（のことなんだけど）やったことある？, which is "Have you played it?  I mean, that new game". This shows "that game" is independent from the following clause yet not so important as to highlight with は.

Comment: @user4092 oh I see, thanks as usual. Some of those things might be a bit too much to take in at first, but I’m sure I’ll catch up pretty soon ^ ^